# Decarboxylation product of bicyclic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

What is the decarboxylation product of the following species:
[image]

It may seem straightforward but the product enolate involves a double bond with one end at the bridgehead carbon which is impossible/very unstable. What is the correct product and how is the product reached mechanistically.

Comment: Could the resulting enol tautomerize?

Comment: Yes it could. But the enolate must surely form initially?

Comment: Enolization is a blindingly fast reaction.  Even though the intermediate is unstable, the easy pathway forward might allow formation of the resulting ketone, despite the bridgehead.

Answer (score 4):

${\beta}$-keto acids typically decarboxylate very smoothly at temperatures between 100-200°C. The mechanism involves a cyclic, 6-membered transition state that first produces an enol intermediate (see figure).

[image]

However in the case of your bicyclo[2.2.1] ${\beta}$-keto acid, a bridgehead double bond would result.  As you correctly point out, such a structure would be very high energy.  Therefore **this compound does not decarboxylate** at normal temperatures ([reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zr7algbSigoC&pg=PA217&lpg=PA217&dq=decarboxylation%20of%20bridgehead%20keto%20acid&source=bl&ots=iUxZSPi48U&sig=tox5gzY6UMx3DIC_UpGStW8t3BU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3ZElVdv7CYrysAXAi4G4AQ&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=decarboxylation%20of%20bridgehead%20keto%20acid&f=false), see p. 218, scheme 6.53).

I'm sure if you heated it hot enough something would happen.  It may decarboxylate *via* a free radical mechanism. The resultant bridgehead free radical could fragment or dimerize.  Alternately, and my preferred guess, would have the starting compound, in equilibrium with its non-bridgehead enol tautomer, undergo a reverse Diels-Alder reaction as pictured above.

Comment: My term hasn't started again yet. I'll let you know

Comment: she said that it does not decarboxylate

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this.  So is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Well, she just said it wouldn't decarboxylate. I didn't offer her your response as a possibility I'm afraid. Although, she seemed to suggest heating it wouldn't decarboxylate it. She didn't suggest anything else so I guess nothing happens until it combusts.

Comment: You're a hard grader, but that's fine :)  You asked if the compound decarboxylated, I correctly answered "no" and correctly explained why.  I then added an aside for the interested reader who might want to know something beyond the original question.